# .post-text img has bottom margin

Tags: bug, design

`.post-text img` has a bottom margin of 15px, which is inconsistent with the preview/rest of the network. It makes the Town Hall Chat digests sad, and should be removed:

[image: image with unnecessary bottom margin]